# Why am I always getting "The multi-part identifier Column could not be bound"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL Server and I want to compare a value from one column with another value from another column. The flow was like this:

```
if value from table1 != value from table 2     
continue
```

...but how do I just compare the value from the columns.

If I do `SELECT @variable=COLUMN FROM TABLE and IF @variable1!=@variable2`, it is not working.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT @AgentID=AGENTID
       ,@CreateTime1=CREATEDATE 
FROM AGENT

SELECT @Agid=AgentNo
       ,@CreateTime2=[Join Date]
       ,@AccCount2=AgentID 
FROM LOCALDB_AGENT

IF @CreateTime1>@CreateTime2 
        BEGIN
        IF @AgentID!=@Agid 
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO LOCALDB_AGENT (AgentName,AgentID,AgentNo,Email,[Join Date],CreatedDate)
            SELECT [FIRSTNAME],[AGENTID],[AGENTID],[EMAIL],CREATEDATE,GetDate() AS CreatedDate
            FROM AGENT
            WHERE @AgentID!=@Agid

            SELECT @AccCount2=COUNT(*) 
            FROM LOCALDB_AGENT 
            WHERE [Status]='ACTIVE' AND CreatedDate=Getdate()

            SET @msg = 'New Record to DMTM' + ' = ' + @AccCount2 + char(10)
            PRINT @msg
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            PRINT 'Data Already Exist'
            END
        END
```

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: and sample data too

Answer (score -1):

Option1:

```
IF (SELECT 1) != (SELECT 2)
BEGIN
 PRINT 'CONTINUE'
END
```

Else you can use a `variable` to store the column value and then compare the variables.

Option2:

```
DECLARE @Variable1 INT
DECLARE @Variable2 INT

SELECT @Variable1 = 1
SELECT @Variable2 = 2

IF @Variable1 != @Variable2
BEGIN
 PRINT 'CONTINUE'
END
```

REPLACE the `SELECT Statement` with your query

Comment: You do realize that his `SELECT AGENTID, CREATEDATE FROM AGENT` may/may not fetch single row. I think he expects to pass single value in his variables. That's where he is stuck.

Comment: Yup, I did see that.. but his requirement was how to compare the values. Thats the reason why I stated "REPLACE the SELECT Statement with your query"